# Opting out from Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics

We have Google Tag Manager implemented as below:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I've been looking around for code to opt out from GTM. Is there such code? What I found is for UA `window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXX-Y'] = true;`

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Is this for the purpose of GDPR compliance?

You could create a custom javascript variable in GTM that checks to see if user has opted into cookie tracking and place that as a condition inside all other events.

Does that help? Or do you need it to be disabled sooner?